# sql server - adding row to the query result set with no data

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that returns the averages and counts for a test in a given instance of a school year, and I need to include the test instances for a certain school year in the result set that don't have don't data. I have the query below, the result set, the desired result, and the passed variables.

```
SELECT  y.SchoolYearDescription, c.TestPeriodTitle, ti.pkTestInstanceID, ti.fkTestPeriodID AS 'fkTestPeriodID', ISNULL(SUM(a.AverageScore * Count),0) / ISNULL(SUM(a.Count),0) /*AverageScore*/ AS 'AvgScaledScore', ISNULL(SUM(Count),0) /*Count*/ AS 'Count_Include'
    FROM RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local_Averages a
    INNER JOIN RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local g ON g.pkSummarySubjectLocalID = a.fkSummarySubjectLocalID
    RIGHT JOIN MM_SchoolYears y ON g.fkSchoolYearID = y.pkSchoolYearID
    INNER JOIN itot(@strYearIds, N',') tblYearIds ON y.pkSchoolYearID = tblYearIds.number
    INNER JOIN TestInstances ti ON ti.pkTestInstanceID = g.fkTestInstanceID
    INNER JOIN itot(@strTestInstIds, N',') tblTestInstIds ON ti.pkTestInstanceID = tblTestInstIds.number
    INNER JOIN CAHSEE_TestPeriods c ON c.pkTestPeriodID = ti.fkTestPeriodID
    WHERE g.fkRosterSetID = @intRosterSetId
        AND g.fkTestTypeID = @intTestTypeId
        AND g.fkTest_SubjectID = @intSubId
        AND a.fkScoreTypeID = @intScoreTypeId
        AND g.fkSchoolID = @intSchoolId
        AND g.fkGradeID = @intGradeId
        AND g.fkDepartmentID = @intDeptId
        AND g.fkCourseID = @intCourseId
        AND g.fkPeriodID = @intPeriodId 
        AND g.fkDemoCommonCodeID IN (SELECT number FROM itot(@strDemoCodeIds, N','))
    GROUP BY y.SchoolYearDescription, ti.pkTestInstanceID, c.TestPeriodTitle, ti.fkTestPeriodID
    ORDER BY y.SchoolYearDescription, ti.pkTestInstanceID, c.TestPeriodTitle, ti.fkTestPeriodID
```

The returned result looks like this. There is no data for the 2012 - 2013 year so it is not included in the result.

```
SchoolYearDescription   TestPeriodTitle   pkTestInstanceID   fkTestPeriodID  AvgScaledScore   Count_Include
2013-2014               2013 Fall         296                417             163              26
2014-2015               2014 Fall         300                421             169              34
```

But I want the result to include the 2012 - 2013 fall test administration with no data and fill the score and count columns with zeros like this:

```
SchoolYearDescription   TestPeriodTitle   pkTestInstanceID   fkTestPeriodID  AvgScaledScore   Count_Include
2012-2013               2012 Fall         292                413             0                0 
2013-2014               2013 Fall         296                417             163              26
2014-2015               2014 Fall         300                421             169              34
```

I am passing these variables to the query (stored procedure)

```
    @strYearIds = N'13,14,15',
    @strDemoCodeIds = N'0',
    @intRosterSetId = 0,
    @intSchoolId = 0,
    @intTeachId = 0,
    @intGradeId = 99,
    @intDeptId = 0,
    @intCourseId = 0,
    @intPeriodId = 0,
    @intSubId = 1139,
    @strTestInstId = N'292,296,300',
    @intTestTypeId = 25,
    @intPerfLevelReportId = 25,
    @bitIsStrand = 0
```

Is this sort of thing possible to accomplish or pretty complicated? Let me know if more information is needed to answer the question.

Comment: does your table MM_SchoolYears  contain all the years, if not we need to generate all years using CTE and then do left join.

Comment: @TabAlleman Well, since those zeros don't actually exist in the data the OUTER JOINS do not help my cause whatsoever

Comment: @RADAR Yes all the years are in MM_SchoolYears and all the test instances are in TestInstances

Comment: @TabAlleman Yes the values do not exist in the data.

Comment: @TabAlleman That's the point... I want that in the result for each test instance that's asked in the variable even if it doesn't have data.

Comment: You're not understanding my question.  Your desired result has 292 for the pkTestInstanceID for 2012-2013 school year.   Where does 292 come from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64815/discussion-between-ryan-gray-and-tab-alleman).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're getting your core data from your TestInstances table, so you want to get rows from that table regardless of whether they link to your Averages table.   I think this will work:

```
SELECT  y.SchoolYearDescription, c.TestPeriodTitle, ti.pkTestInstanceID, ti.fkTestPeriodID AS 'fkTestPeriodID', ISNULL(SUM(a.AverageScore * Count),0) / ISNULL(SUM(a.Count),0) /*AverageScore*/ AS 'AvgScaledScore', ISNULL(SUM(Count),0) /*Count*/ AS 'Count_Include'
    FROM RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local_Averages a
    RIGHT JOIN RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local g ON g.pkSummarySubjectLocalID = a.fkSummarySubjectLocalID
    RIGHT JOIN MM_SchoolYears y ON g.fkSchoolYearID = y.pkSchoolYearID
    LEFT JOIN itot(@strYearIds, N',') tblYearIds ON y.pkSchoolYearID = tblYearIds.number
    RIGHT JOIN TestInstances ti ON ti.pkTestInstanceID = g.fkTestInstanceID
    LEFT JOIN itot(@strTestInstIds, N',') tblTestInstIds ON ti.pkTestInstanceID = tblTestInstIds.number
    LEFT JOIN CAHSEE_TestPeriods c ON c.pkTestPeriodID = ti.fkTestPeriodID
    WHERE g.fkRosterSetID = @intRosterSetId
        AND g.fkTestTypeID = @intTestTypeId
        AND g.fkTest_SubjectID = @intSubId
        AND a.fkScoreTypeID = @intScoreTypeId
        AND g.fkSchoolID = @intSchoolId
        AND g.fkGradeID = @intGradeId
        AND g.fkDepartmentID = @intDeptId
        AND g.fkCourseID = @intCourseId
        AND g.fkPeriodID = @intPeriodId 
        AND g.fkDemoCommonCodeID IN (SELECT number FROM itot(@strDemoCodeIds, N','))
    GROUP BY y.SchoolYearDescription, ti.pkTestInstanceID, c.TestPeriodTitle, ti.fkTestPeriodID
    ORDER BY y.SchoolYearDescription, ti.pkTestInstanceID, c.TestPeriodTitle, ti.fkTestPeriodID
```